# Uncountably many pre-measure extensions

Tags: measure-theory

I am given a pre-measure $\mu$ on the semi-ring $\mathcal{J}$ over $\mathbb{R}$ with $\mu(\emptyset) = 0$ and $\mu(I) = +\infty$ for all non-empty $I \in \mathcal{J}$.

I want to show that there are uncountably many measures which extend $\mu$ on $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$. I am not sure how to approach this. Can someone give me an outline/hints how to prove this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The extension of a premeasure on a semiring $J$ to the borel sets](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2037194/the-extension-of-a-premeasure-on-a-semiring-j-to-the-borel-sets)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This statement is false in the given setting… see my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2037194/the-extension-of-a-premeasure-on-a-semiring-j-to-the-borel-sets/2037729#2037729).

Unfortunatly I can't tag your question as doubled because the questioner missed to flag my answer there…